# R not importing csv file correctly

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a strange problem with R. It does not import a csv file correctly that I am exporting from Excel. I have the following csv file (I checked that the text format was the same as the cell values in Excel):

```
REGION;TYPE;CODE;BILL
A;X;871685920001760387;003007614504
B;Y ;871685920001765726;003007638434
C;Z;871685920001804326;003211001858
```

The above are the contents of my csv file. I saved it as "Example.csv". Now I want to import this file into R:

```
Ex <- read.csv2("Example.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Now, I specifically want to check that the CODE column matches, for I need these values to compare them against some files that I have stored elsewhere. However, when I compare these files to the tekst file (and the cell values in Excel), using `options(digits = 19)`;

```
Ex$CODE
[1] 871685920001760384 871685920001765760 871685920001804288
```

As you can see, these values do not match at all! Trying `as.character()` gives the same results:

```
as.character(Ex$CODE)
[1] "871685920001760384" "871685920001765760" "871685920001804288"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I also tried `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` which did not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally a CSV file has the format "one", "two", "three". I would check the settings of the export in Excel.

Comment: Have you tried using read.csv rather than read.csv2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read them all in as characters by setting `colClasses`.

```
 > Ex = read.table("Example.csv", sep  = ";", header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")
 > Ex
   REGION TYPE               CODE         BILL
 1      A    X 871685920001760387 003007614504
 2      B   Y  871685920001765726 003007638434
 3      C    Z 871685920001804326 003211001858
!> sapply(Ex, class)
      REGION        TYPE        CODE        BILL
 "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

Comment: Works great! That was easy! Thanks!

Comment: @Tim.Lucas See James' explanation for why this happens. Look at `?.Machine` for more information

Answer (score 6):

@JakeBurkhead gave the solution, but the reason why this is happening is because `read.csv` by default will interpret the values as `numeric`. `numeric` values are constrained by the rules of floating point arithmetic, particularly that of [doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

This is how R interprets the value:

```
print(871685920001760387,digits=18)
[1] 871685920001760384
```

Doubles carry 53 bits of precision for a number, which is a little less than 10^16. Your number is almost 10^18, and therefore it cannot be represented exactly down to the unit level.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the explanation! Will keep this in mind.